# ZAP Hud broken after hardening the application a bit

Tags: spring, zap, content-security-policy

I am in the process of performing a security scan of a PoC Spring Boot application, deployed under AWS ECS.

First round of scan, I discovered issues with CSP, cookies, XSS (that's what ZAP is for!), etc.
I added some Spring Security configuration to my application to *harden* it a bit.

Now that I want to scan the application again, the HUD is totally broken and won't display

[image: Broken frame]

While it's a PoC running on H2 and I see no security issue, I won't post for now the URL to it. It's in the form of http://bg-lb-op-xxxxxx.eu-central-1.elb.amazonaws.com/app/

- Zap loads it from HTTPS while I have no SSL binding on it
- Chrome insists on the following error `Error while parsing the 'sandbox' attribute: 'allow-storage-access-by-user-activation' is an invalid sandbox flag.`
- And there is the https error `Mixed Content: The page at 'https://bg-lb-op-xxxxxxx/......' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://bg-lb-op-xxxxxxxx/.... This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.`

Example response headers as captured by Chrome

```
HTTP/1.1 200
Date: Tue, 11 Jul 2023 10:34:14 GMT
Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8
Connection: keep-alive
Set-Cookie: AWSALBTG=xxxxxxxx; Expires=Tue, 18 Jul 2023 10:34:14 GMT; Path=/
Set-Cookie: AWSALBTGCORS=xxxxxxxx; Expires=Tue, 18 Jul 2023 10:34:14 GMT; Path=/; SameSite=None
Set-Cookie: AWSALB=xxxxxxx; Expires=Tue, 18 Jul 2023 10:34:14 GMT; Path=/
Set-Cookie: AWSALBCORS=xxxxx; Expires=Tue, 18 Jul 2023 10:34:14 GMT; Path=/; SameSite=None
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: 0
X-Frame-Options: DENY
Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy: unsafe-none
Cross-Origin-Embedder-Policy: require-corp
Cross-Origin-Resource-Policy: same-site
Content-Length: 2799
```

After the first scan I added the following Spring security configuration

```java
@Bean
@Order
public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
    return httpSecurity
            .authorizeRequests(request -> request
                    .antMatchers("/js/**", "/styles/**", "/images/**", "/favicon.ico").permitAll()
                    .antMatchers("/ping/**").permitAll()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated()
            )
            .formLogin(form -> form
                    .loginPage("/login")
                    .successHandler(authenticationSuccessHandler)
                    .permitAll()
            )
            .logout(withDefaults())
            .csrf(withDefaults())
            .headers(headers -> headers
                    .httpStrictTransportSecurity(withDefaults())
                    .cacheControl(withDefaults())
                    .contentTypeOptions(withDefaults())
                    .xssProtection().xssProtectionEnabled(true).block(true).and()
                    .referrerPolicy(ReferrerPolicyHeaderWriter.ReferrerPolicy.NO_REFERRER).and()
                    .crossOriginEmbedderPolicy().policy(CrossOriginEmbedderPolicyHeaderWriter.CrossOriginEmbedderPolicy.REQUIRE_CORP).and()
                    .crossOriginOpenerPolicy().policy(CrossOriginOpenerPolicyHeaderWriter.CrossOriginOpenerPolicy.UNSAFE_NONE).and()
                    .crossOriginResourcePolicy().policy(CrossOriginResourcePolicyHeaderWriter.CrossOriginResourcePolicy.SAME_SITE).and()
                    .frameOptions(HeadersConfigurer.FrameOptionsConfig::deny)
                    .contentSecurityPolicy(csp -> csp.policyDirectives("base-uri 'self'; " +
                            "default-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' https://cdn.jsdelivr.net https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com https://ajax.googleapis.com; " +
                            "style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' https://cdn.jsdelivr.net https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com https://ajax.googleapis.com; " +
                            "font-src https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com;" +
                            "connect-src 'self'; " +
                            "worker-src 'none'; " +
                            "frame-src 'none'; " +
                            "form-action 'self';"))
            )
            .build();
}
```

From what I can see, security headers are messing with ZAP's injection tool. If I roll everything back, I can see the HUD again. But I knew that ZAP should try to filter out the headers that may interfere with its own injection tool.

I can't retest the application to confirm that past issues are fixed.

Is there anything I have missed/messed?